# jsPlumb endpoints issue after upgrade

Tags: endpoint, jsplumb

After upgrading from jsPlumb 1.4.1 to 1.7.10, **the endpoints are far away from the nodes**, but they do move with the node.

To fix it, I tried:

```
jsPlumbInstance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
    DragOptions: {cursor: 'pointer', zIndex: 1000},
    Container: $("#idContainer")
});
```

and in addition:

```
var inputEndpoint = jsPlumbInstance.addEndpoint($('#' + parent.attr('id')), {
    anchor:[ 0.01 - xPadOffset, increment, -1, 0 ],
    endpoint:"Rectangle",
    paintStyle:{ width: padWidth, height:padAndLabelHeight/2, fillStyle:'#822' },
    isTarget:true,
    maxConnections: -1,
    cssClass: 'inputEndpointClass',
    overlays:[[ "Label", { label: name, location: [0.5, -0.32], cssClass: 'labelClass' } ]]
});
```

This displays the endpoints perfectly, but now they do not move with the node.

Can anyone be so kind to put me on the right track? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed now. There were a number of problems. I work out the size of the node according to the container size and there was a problem with the calculation. Also my nodes were relative in a relative container, which caused problems. The container had a minimum height that caused a problem too.